# Enabling Flash Player to run in the background

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, youtube, adobe-flash

On all the Android devices I've ever had, I've never seen one that could actually allow flash music streaming or YouTube to run in the background on a minimized window.

For example, if you are on a music streaming website, as long as that web page is in the foreground the audio will play. However, if you need to minimize that window and open another tab, for example, the flash stream stops.

It's the exact same way for YouTube; as long as the video is open in the foreground window the music will play.

Is there any way to put those in background, but have their sound continue to play?

Comment: All I can find so far is [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=885868) which suggests nobody has done it. It is possible to do sure, but I can't find it anywhere in reality. I'll keep looking for you and maybe someone else will know. You can do this with youtube,  but the only way I know off the top of my head requires root and Xposed framework. I've meetings now but I'll look later if I have the time. Maybe [something like this for YouTube?](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.asbit.pvstar&hl=en) I haven't tried it though, sorry.

Comment: Wasn't that a feature announced with one of the recent Youtube updates? But whatever: App recommendations are off-topic here; to prevent the question from being "dropped", I'd suggest rephrasing it into "Is there any way to allow..." ;) … Done. Hope that's fine with you.

Comment: You would have to intall tasker then a script.  I don't know if anybody wrote a script on that so you'll have to research. Xposed framework also could be possible solution like Ross suggested,  you'll just have to find a module for that.